# Why does my processor on Windows 10 run hotter than Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, cpu, temperature

I recently switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I also have an Intel 4770k and an NVIDIA GTX 970. On Windows 10, my processor typically idles around 8% CPU usage and runs about 45 degrees Celsius. I see this as normal.

When running games on Windows 10, such as Overwatch, it causes my CPU to heat up much more than on Windows 7. I would rarely see my CPU reach core temperatures above 75 degrees Celsius. On Windows 10, the temperature is reaching around 95 degrees Celsius.

My GPU runs at the same temperatures.

My current intel driver version is 10.0.14393.0, which Windows 10 says is the most up-to-date driver.

Comment: is your game using the intel integrated gpu instead of your graphics card?

Comment: windows 10 includes more garbage that runs at background (apps, cortana, background tasks) this causes higher CPU usage and temperature.

Comment: The game is using the GTX 970. And I don't think the background processes of WIndows 10 is making a difference. Like I said, I run about 45C at 8% CPU usage on idle.

Comment: yes, I had the same issue during my testings. CPU was 10°C hotter in Win10 compared to Win8.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Have you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: nope, that is why I'm still on Win8 on my laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 is heavily optimized for modern CPUs with many cores. It's doing a better job of using all the resources on your CPU and, as a result, the CPU is running hotter. 75C is perfectly reasonable for a 4770K under load and doesn't indicate any problem.

Comment: 75C is on Windows 7. 95C is on Windows 10.

Comment: @ButterJones You shouldn't have accepted his answer if it didn't answer your question... which it didn't.